# Converting comma separated string into array and few more things

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a site which has two textboxes. The first one is for email and the second for a message. When someone enters their email and a message and presses submit it shows the submitted message on the home page. Unfortunately, it doesn't send email to anyone.

Now I want to make it possible to write multiple emails and when you press submit what it does is show each email/message separately and not one message with 3-4 emails(whatever emails you typed). The message is the same of course. Here is my _forms code http://pastie.org/private/wg5naoay5hxbvxmnp02sbg

I found out that first I have to separate string into arrays with .split(',') method.
I am not sure if I should do that in _forms file or model? Also after I do that split method, how to make it write out same message for each email separately and not one message with all those emails? If you need code let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this method in Helper

```
def emails
  emails_array= email_string.split(',')
  Mailer.send_mail(emails_array)
end
```

Put this in Mailer

```
Class Mailer     
  def send_email emails
    emails.each do |email|
       ##your sending email logic for each email address
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Soory, but I don't understund. I don't have neither helper or mailer. I just got one model here is how it looks http://pastie.org/private/7gfmhjxngxbbefvfsh4cew

Comment: you have to create on. At same level where models folder exists

Comment: For Mailers. You need to create one more folder named as mailers in app folder